# Testing interactions with external services

Tags: java, unit-testing, testing, playframework

*prerequisites: I'm using the latest version of the [Play! framework](http://www.playframework.org/), and the Java version (not Scala).*

I need to publish a message to a message queue when a user is created, and I'd like to test that behaviour. My issue is making this easily testable.

## The Controller approach

In other frameworks, what I would've done would be to use constructor injection in the controller and pass in a mocked queue in my tests; however, with Play! the controllers are static, that means I can't do `new MyController(mockedQueue)` in my tests.

I could use Google Guice and put an `@Inject` annotation on a static field in my controller, but that doesn't feel very nice to me, as it either means I have to make the field public to be replaced in the test, or I have to use a container in my tests. I'd much prefer to use constructor injection, but Play! doesn't seem to facilitate that.

## The Model approach

It's often said your logic should be in your model, not your controller. That makes sense; however, we're not in Ruby here and having your entities interact with external services (email, message queues etc...) is considerably less testable than in a dynamic environment where you could just replace your `MessageQueue` static calls with a mocked instance at will.

If I make my entity call off to the queue, how is that testable?

Of course, both these situations are unnecessary if I do end-to-end integration tests, but I'd rather not need a message queue or SMTP server spun up for my tests to run.

**So my question is:** How do I model my Play! controllers and/or models to facilitate testing interactions with external services?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I see, there's not a clean solution for this.

You could use an [Abstract Factory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_factory_pattern) for your dependencies. This factory could have setter methods for the objects it produces.

```
public class MyController {
    ...
    private static ServiceFactory serviceFactory = ServiceFactory.getInstance();
    ...
    public static void action() {
        ...
        QueueService queue = serviceFactory.getQueueService();
        ...
    }
```

}

Your test would look like this:

```
public void testAction() {
    QueueService mock = ...
    ...
    ServiceFactory serviceFactory = ServiceFactory.getInstance();
    serviceFactory.setQueueService(mock);
    ...
    MyController.action();
    verify(mock);
}
```

If you don't want to expose the setter methods of the factory, you could create an interface and configure the implementing class in your tests.

Another option would be the use o [PowerMock](http://code.google.com/p/powermock/) for mocking static methods. I've used before and it works relatively fine for most cases. Just don't overuse it, or you're in maintenance hell...

And finally, since your willing to use Guice in your application, [this](http://ericlefevre.net/wordpress/2011/05/08/play-framework-and-guice-use-providers-in-guice-modules/) could be a viable option.

Good luck!

Comment: One *potential* issue with the `ServiceFactory` approach is when the field will be initialized; as it's a static field, `getInstance` may be called by the initializer before you get the opportunity to replace the instance. Just thinking out loud, not actually verified this.

Comment: Actually, in the example, ServiceFactory is a Singleton. You wouldn't be replacing the ServiceFactory itself, but the QueueService it 'produces'.

Comment: Yep, I understand that; however, as the field is static there's a possibility it would be initialized before you're able to to replace whatever value would be returned from `getInstance`. You generally don't have control over when the static initializer is executed, so it may happen before your test setup occurs.

Comment: Ok, I understand your concern, but we are not actually mocking the ServiceFactory. The method `getInstance()` will always return the same Singleton instance (the ServiceFactory instance), whether we call it in a test or in production code. We are configuring the ServiceFactory, so we can replace the value returned from the method `getQueueService()`.

Comment: I see that now, thanks. Seems a little strange that `ServiceFactory` effectively returns singletons, but I can understand the justification. Thanks, it was my mistake.

Comment: Well, the `ServiceFactory` doesn't have to return singleton instances for every service it produces. It's just that, in the example, the ServiceFactory is a singleton it self. The `getInstance()` gives access to the `ServiceFactory` instance.

Answer (score 2):

I'm little confused. You can call a method of another class

```
public class Users extends Controller {
    public static void save(@Valid User user) {
    //check for user validaton
    user = user.save();
    QueueService queueService = new QueueSerice();
    queueService.publishMessage(user);
    }
}
```

You can write unit testcases for **QueueService** using a mock and write Functional testcase for **Users** controller **save** method.

Comment: Maybe I wasn't clear. How would you replace `new QueueService()` with a mock instance in your test? Or are you saying that you'd unit test the `QueueService`, but only do a functional test of the interaction between the `User` and the `QueueService`?

Comment: If that's the way to go, fine; but in most other frameworks I've dealt with, it's perfectly feasible to test the interaction between the two without requiring that there be an actual live queue available.

Answer (score 2):

EDIT: extending answer as previous was not clear

The first idea would be to add the reference to the Queue to the Model, as you have a POJO and access to the constructor. As you mention in the comments below, the Model approach is problematic when thinking on Hibernate hydrating the entity, which would discard this.

The second approach would be to add this reference to the Queue to the Controller. Now, this seems like a bad idea. Besides the public member issue you mention, I believe that the idea behind the controller is to retrieve the parameters to the request, validate they are correct (checkAuthenticity, validation, etc), send the request to be processed and then prepare the response.

The "key" here is "send the request to be processed". In some cases we may do that work in the Controller if it is simple, but in other cases it seems better to use a "Service" (to call it somehow) in which you do the work you need with the given data.

I use this separation as from the point of view of testing it's easier (for me) to test the controller via Selenium and do a separate test (using JUnit) for the service.

In you case this Service would include the reference to the Queue you mention.

On how to initialize, that will depend. You may create a singleton, initialize it every time via a constructor, etc. In you particular scenario this may depend on the work related to initialize your queue service: if it's hard you may want a Singleton with a Factory method that retrieves the service (and can be mocked in testing) and pass that as a parameter to the constructor of the Service object.

Hope this update clarifies more what I had in mind when I answered.

Comment: Chicken and the egg. So where does the factory come from? A singleton?

Comment: Chicken and egg? :| You may have a static factory method, in a  singleton or a utility class or somewhere. Its only aim is to return the Queue object that you need. I mean, what other way do you want to do it? I'm afraid I don't see the problem or I don't understand your objection.

Comment: In any other framework, I'd use constructor injection (with or without a container). Using singletons or factory methods only serve to hide what dependencies a class truly has.

Comment: But Model has constructor... and that's where you wanted to put it...and entity is a POJO, absolutely testable...

Comment: Except when it's a model which gets hydrated by Hibernate.

Answer (score 1):

It is perhaps not what you are looking for, but in my current project we have solved that type of testing through integration tests and a JMS setup with a local queue and a messaging bridge.

In slightly more detail:

- Your code always posts/reads messages to/from local queues, i.e. queues on your local app server (not on the external system).
- A messaging bridge connects the local queue to the queue of the external service when needed, e.g. in production or in a manual testing environment.
- An integration test creates the new user (or whatever you want to test), and then reads the expected message from the local queue. In this case, the messaging bridge is not active.

On my project, we use [SoapUI](http://www.soapui.org/) to perform these tests as the system under test is a SOAP-based integration platform and SoapUI has good JMS support. But it could just as well be a plain JUnit test which performs the test and reads from the local JMS queue afterwards.